# Can RSA re-encrypt a message without decrypting it?

Tags: encryption, rsa, modular-arithmetic, proxy-re-encryption

*The goal of this question is to allow a server/proxy to forward an encrypted message without being able to read it with this procedure being transparent to the original sender and receiver.*

Assume we have Admin RSA Keys $(e,d,n)$ and Bob RSA Keys $(e_b,d_b,n_b)$ where Alice wants to send a message $m$ to Bob with only knowing the *Admin's* public key $(e,n)$. She sends $c_0 = m^e \mod n$ to a proxy where $c_0$ is transformed to $c_1$ which is forwarded to Bob who decrypts it as $m = c_1^{d_b} \mod n_b$.

The magic is in the transformation from $c_0$ to $c_1$ **without** giving the proxy the Admin's private key $d$.

My thinking here is that **if (!)** $n = n_b$ we could compute a re-encryption key
$$
r = d \cdot e_b
$$ in advance. If we also could **protect** $r$ in such a way that the proxy is unable to retrieve $d$ from $r/e_b$, I believe we could simply compute
$$
c_1 = c_0^{r} \mod n_b
$$

These are a lot of assumptions that will not likely hold in practice. Especially, the biggest difference will be that $n \neq n_b$.
So the question is, can these obstacles be overcome with modulo arithmetic or is there another way to create a re-encryption (pseudo-)key in RSA that prevents retrieval of $m$ while transforming $c_0$ to $c_1$.

Comment: Remark: When $n_a=n_b$, Alice/Admin can factor $n_a=n_b$ and find a working private key $(n_b,d_b)$ for Bob if she knows her own $d_a$, and Bob's public key $(n_b,e_b)$. The only cryptographic way to prevent A from impersonating B or decrypting messages for B (or vice-versa) is to enforce use of a black-box implementation of RSA (e.g. Smart Card) that does not let the key leak. But breaking any such device breaks them all, like in symmetric crypto.

Comment: @fgrieu This might have been confusing in the question, but the $_a$ keys do not belong to Alice but to Admin. However, I fully realise that $n_a = n_b$ is a silly assumption. The question is about how the sketch presented here can be moved up to a realistic setting where $n_a \neq n_b$. I changed the Admin's keys from $(e_a,d_a,n_a)$ to $(e,d,n)$.

Comment: Yes, fixed for the most. The academic term for what you are looking at is Proxy Re-Cryptography (PRC). [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916004239/http://ndc.zjgsu.edu.cn/~jshao/prcbib.htm) used to gather references. There are tons of articles on the subject. I would advise to initially limit to those in [IACR peer-reviewed publications](https://iacr.org/publications/). \[apologies for a misclick deleting a comment\].

Comment: @fgrieu Ah yes, that term was unknown to me. As cryptography is not my main field I would still be interested in an explanatory answer, digesting the academic research.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=proxy+encryption